# Android Smooth fill the list with new items from top

Tags: android, listview, smoothing

so here is my setup:

I have a listview with a custom adapter and i have methods which add new items to the list from the top. This works without an issue but i am looking to tweak it and make it better.

so here is my issue: right now when i call notifyDataSetChanged() the items are added to the list but that happens instantly and it is kinda rough and you can't really see which items have been added.

what i want to do is actually have some sort of animation when the items are added so it appears like the old ones are pushed down and that be visible to the user (maybe last 300 ms per item or 2 seconds for a total of maybe 5-10 items)

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make tween animation for the listView. But I am not sure whether only new or all items are going o be animated when notifyDataSetChanged is called

Comment: i am pretty sure it will animate the whole list. my idea was to keep a flag for the new items and set an animation on the listView adapter item to grow in size or something and mark the flag as true after the animation is started and start only if the flag is false. so the old items that were previously shown in the list will have the flag as false and the new ones as true which will start an animation.

Comment: Have you tried to smoothly adjust possition of you listview by calling scrollBy or smoothScrollBy? You can make new thread (AsyncTask) for this animation.